# Помогите измерить производительность и использование памяти (программно)?

Tags: c#, память, производительность

```
static void builder()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("This is a builder ");
        sw.Start();
        strBuilder.Append("string");
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(strBuilder);
        long ticksForBuilder = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        Console.WriteLine("Производительность билдера = " + ticksForBuilder);
        sw.Reset();
    }
```

Comment: Смотрите [методы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc?view=net-6.0#methods) класса GC, которые начинаются на `Get`.

Comment: Это называется бенчмарки. Берите готовый NuGet пакет **Benchmark.NET** и пользуйтесь. Он вам и память, и скорость, и другие полезные характеристики посчитает, и даже графиков для профилирования производительности в разных условиях нарисует. Велосипед уже есть. Возможно на нем ездить не так удобно и легко, как вам кажется, но задачу он выполняет свою на отлично, изучить его однозначно стоит.

Comment: [Замеряем производительность с помощью BenchmarkDotNet](https://habr.com/ru/post/277177/)

Comment: Вы пишете "программно" - что вы подразумеваете под этим? Если вы хотите замерить производительность своего приложения, то используйте Benchmark.NET (также посмотрите книгу Pro .NET
Benchmarking, Akinshin). А если именно сами хотите написать такой код, то, кроме класса GC, смотрите [Metrics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics) и [EventCounters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters).